# PowerShell function return value

Tags: powershell

Consider:

```
function func {
    echo ALERT
    return $false
}

if (func) {
    Write-Output "TRUE"
}
```

This code writes TRUE despite the function returning false. However, when I write `[void]echo ALERT`, PowerShell throws an error:

> Unexpected token 'echo' in expression or statement.

How do I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo ALERT` in your code returns a string (`echo` is an alias for [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output)).

If you make an `if` check on a string, PowerShell checks if the string is not null or empty.

Therefore it always returns true.

If you want to alert the user of the "ALERT", use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host).

```
function func {
    Write-Host ALERT
    return $false
}
```

Comment: Why I can't simply write [void]echo (it throws error)? I had to wrap echo in {} i. e. [void]{echo ALERT} to make code pass syntax check.